# I hope someone can improve the python-grpc example of veriblock

Tags: veriblock

Veriblock has no python-grpc example. The return information may not be available due to coding problems. I'm not sure. I hope someone can make an example. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey there. Unfortunately this is not worded as a question, but a request. 

If you have a specific question you'd like to pose, maybe check out [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to writing a succesful question then post again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a more comprehensive example, but for connecting via gRPC and displaying current block number and node info this should get you started.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json
import grpc
import veriblock_pb2 as vbk
import veriblock_pb2_grpc as vbkrpc


channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:10500')
stub = vbkrpc.AdminStub(channel)

def GetStateInfoRequest():
    response = stub.GetStateInfo(vbk.GetStateInfoRequest())
    response = json.dumps({"connected_peer_count": response.connected_peer_count,
                   "network_height": response.network_height,
                   "local_blockchain_height": response.local_blockchain_height,
                   "network_version": response.network_version,
                   "program_version": response.program_version,
                   "nodecore_starttime": response.nodecore_starttime,
                   "wallet_cache_sync_height": response.wallet_cache_sync_height})
    print(response)

def getBlock():
    response = stub.GetInfo(vbk.GetInfoRequest())
    response = (response.number_of_blocks - 1)
    print(response)

getBlock()
GetStateInfoRequest()
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific python question, like calling a function or API or expecting output?

VeriBlock NodeCore does support python, via grpc (https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python.html)

FWIW, there is a pre-compiled output for grpc that includes python
https://github.com/VeriBlock/nodecore-releases/releases/tag/v0.4.1-grpc
python
    veriblock_pb2.py
    veriblock_pb2_grpc.py

There is a C# example here: https://github.com/VeriBlock/VeriBlock.Demo.Rpc.Client (obviously not python, but maybe useful as a conceptual example)